# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

I keep getting a `RuntimeException` whenever I execute my test:

```
package com.example.mytipcalculator

import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CalculatorTests() {

    @get:Rule
    val activity = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    fun test(){
        onView(withId(R.id.cost_of_service_edit_text))
        .perform(typeText("50.00"))
        .perform(ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard())

        onView(withId(R.id.increase))
            .perform(click())

        onView(withId(R.id.increase))
            .perform(click())

        onView(withId(R.id.increase))
            .perform(click())

        onView(withId(R.id.increase))
            .perform(click())

        onView(withId(R.id.increase))
            .perform(click())

        onView(withId(R.id.calculate_button))
            .perform(click())

        onView(withId(R.id.tip_result))
            .check(matches(withText(containsString("$10.00"))))

        onView(withId(R.id.totalexpense))
            .check(matches(withText(containsString("$60.00"))))
    }
}
```

When I run the previous code, I get the following initialization error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
Test class class com.example.mytipcalculator.CalculatorTests is malformed. (1 problems):
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.throwInitializationError(AndroidJUnit4.java:129)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:121)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:82)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:56)
... 14 trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:112)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:418)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
... 20 more
```

Comment: You probably have to annotate the `test()` method with the `@Test` annotation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to annotate `test()` method with `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `@JvmField` annotation, I encountered this error when testing jetpack compose.

Before

```kotlin
@Rule
val composeRule = createComposeRule()
```

after

```kotlin
@JvmField
@Rule
val composeRule = createComposeRule()
```